# Switching two relays using the same 1no1nc latching switch

Tags: power-supply, switches, relay

I am working on a device to control power to some telescope devices. I am using a 12 VDC, 20 A power supply block; this will be switched using two relays (10 A each) to the load devices.

I have two LEDs and an LED in the switch, which is why I am going the relay route to prevent the current from actively running through the switch or the status LEDs.

I have the switch working with one relay, however, when I wire the second relay up by connecting the ground from relay 1 to the second, it immediately switches the first relay on.

Here is a rough diagram of what I am doing. I am not an electronics engineer by any stretch of the imagination, but I do know my way around a soldering iron!

[image: schematic]

Comment: A relay doesn't have a ground. What are the things you're calling relays here?

Comment: Which relay modules? Is it possible that the IN is supposed to be connected to GND to keep the relay off? (this depends on how the module is designed). Also, VCC is the power supply for the relay coil, not the high switched current, which you would connect to NC, NO or COM (depending on how you want it to switch). Using 12V for this is probably fine, but it depends on the relay module.

Comment: If you can provide the model number of the relay modules you are using people can provided more specific answers.